# Increment from number to alphabet

Tags: c#, algorithm, increment

I am doing a username generator for our project. But the problem is that I don't know the algorithm of the username format.

It goes like this:

```
user0000
user0001
user0002
....
user0009
user000a
user000b
....
user000z
user0010
```

so on and so forth.

Can someone help me form the algorithm of this sequence? thank you in advance.
I'll be using a C# for this project.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your current way of approaching the challenge?

Comment: yes we can help. What is your starting point? where exactly did you get stuck developing a solution?

Comment: I'm stuck of the transition from 9 going to a. i don't have idea how to jump from 9 to a.

Comment: could you post the code how you create the name up to 9 ? may be it becomes obvious then ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a method to get your desired output.

```
private const string CharList = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
public static String GetName(int input)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    while (input != 0)
    {
        result = CharList[input % CharList.Length] + result;
        input /= CharList.Length;
    }
    return "user" + result.PadLeft(4, '0');
}
```

Basically it's a base 36 calculator.